# Is a GFCI outlet subject to NEC 250.130.C.4, ground supplied from same enclosure as power?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

According to [250.130.C.4](https://up.codes/viewer/new_jersey/nfpa-70-2017/chapter/2/wiring-and-protection#250.130_(C)) the ground connection for an outlet may be borrowed if needed from another junction box so long as it comes from the same "enclosure" (subpanel).

If a two-prong outlet is replaced with a GFCI one, a ground connection is not required.  If a ground connection is nevertheless supplied at the GFCI outlet, but from another junction box, is it subject to that code subsection or can it come from a different subpanel?

The purpose of doing so would be to provide 1) equipment ground function other than safety, and 2) placating naive people with $5 outlet testers.

Comment: Why not just rewire the outlet to the other circuit?  What's the point of trying to run a ground to the wrong panel?

Comment: @RobertChapin -- sometimes, the "correct" source of ground may not be accessible (I can't run grounds back to my main panel readily -- luckily, dropping down can get met to where the GEC is exposed, so that's an option in my case)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Right but I didn't say ground.  If there's a circuit on another panel, why not just rewire the outlet to the other panel/circuit?

Comment: @RobertChapin For example to keep loads where needed for load calc or for generator or because grounded circuit is lower ampacity than needed.

Comment: Note if grounded circuit is lower ampacity than needed you are probably also violating another section with EG a 20 amp circuit on a #14 ground wire.   And, hmm, that clearly IS dangerous so that was a bad choice of example.   I take that one back. :)